# How can i reconnect an entity dataset inside using statement when a SQLException occurs?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The situation is that I have a long running method that is looping through thousands of rows and doing processing and updates.  This loop is nested inside my using statement.

The problem is when I came into work in the morning I see that my connection failed at 8pm with a SQLException and I lost 12 hours of processing time.  How can I reconnect and continue processing my loop programatically?

My idea is something like this:

```
using (var _data = new My.EF.MyEntities())
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 17348; i++)
    {
        try
        {
          //Do lots of stuff
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            WriteLogFile("Error at id" + i.ToString(), ex);
            i--;
            if (_data.Database.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _data.  // What?  nothing looks useful here to reconnect
            }
        }

    }
}
```

this is only dev code, not for any production or user environment.  All I'm doing is seeding a database with 10'000's of records and linked records to get an idea for load testing, so i'm not programming for all possibilities, I just want to be able to handle a dropped connection and reconnect if that is possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved my comment to an answer. This is my recommendation without knowing what you're doing in `do lots of stuff`.

Typically with EF you want to spend as little time as is possible inside your using block. Paraphrased from [this EF tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) (among others):

> 1. Get the existing object from DB.
> 2. Change the object name out of Context scope (disconnected mode)
> 3. Pass the modified entity into the method to get its DBEntityEntry object and then mark its state as Modified
> 4. Call SaveChanges() method to update object information into the database.

Spending 12+ hours inside your `using` context sounds like something needs to be redesigned. With that said, here's a recommendation if your modifying existing entities (from memory, may need some syntax tweaking):

```
IEnumerable<EntityTypeYouveDefined> listOfEntities;

using (var _data = new My.EF.MyEntities())
{
    listOfEntities = _data.YourTableName.Where(e => e.SomeConditionOrPropertyOrWhatever);
    //Or some other search predicate to pull what you want to change.
}

foreach(var entity in listOfEntities)
{
    entity.SomeProperty = "what you want to change";
}

using (var _data = new My.EF.MyEntities())
{
    foreach(var entity in listOfEntities)
    {
        _data.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    _data.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here's some code if you're creating new entities:

```
var listOfEntities = new List<EntityTypeYouveDefined>();
for (int i = 0; i < 17348; i++)
{
    var newEntity = new EntityTypeYouveDefined();
    //Build the newEntity relationships here
    listOfEntities.Add(newEntity);
}

using (var _data = new My.EF.MyEntities())
{
    foreach (var entity in listOfEntities)
    {
        _data.Attach(newEntity)
        //You may have to set the entity state to modified here. Can't remember, I'm doing this from memory
    }
    _data.SaveChanges();

}
```

This will minimize the time you spend in that loop and be cleaner. Also, if you need to do this repeatedly, then use a loop *outside* of the `using` block. The `using` block handles the connection to your database for you. You don't need to manage this yourself outside of the connection string in your `app/web.config` file.

Comment: Thanks for the code ideas.  Those won't work as I'm creating EntityA, then adding it so that it gets and ID then creating a tree of other entities with the ID as a FK - however our DB design doesn't use relations so EF doesn't have relations built into it.  We also don't use EF in our application, I'm using it because it is insanely easy to create new poco's and add them in code.  Because of this I'm not wanting to spend the time building relationships in a code first manner (that would take me awhile).  Weird I know.  Right now i'm trying the Using statement inside the for loop.

Comment: If your ID is a `Guid` you can generate the ID upon object creation instead of waiting for EF to assign it one. I don't think EF is what you want... sounds like you're trying to pop a zit with a hammer.

Comment: "trying to pop a zit with a hammer."  sounds like me.  I'm adding about 100,000 entries into our database and trying to do it so all the relations are correct.  EF seemed like an easy way to do it   What would you suggest?

Comment: What are the datatypes of your ID fields? And why are there no relationships defined in your database? Do you have control of this?

Comment: Let's take this to chat then: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35174/cnumbersign

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know one way to solve this might be to dispose the old `_data` object then initialize it again.

```
var _data = new My.EF.MyEntities();
try
{

    for (int i = 1; i < 17348; i++)
    {
        try
        {
          //Do lots of stuff
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            WriteLogFile("Error at id" + i.ToString(), ex);
            i--;
            if (_data.Database.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                ((IDisposable)_data).Dispose();
                _data = new My.EF.MyEntities()
            }
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    if (_data != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)_data).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: That might work if I remove my using statement.  Based on Brandon's answer that may be what I have to do is re-code that architecture then I can recreate the connection each loop and just decrement my counter in the catch block.